# Firefox add-on set global variable from *.port.on()

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have no clue why this won't work.  vars text and size are coming up as undefined even though I set them in control_window.port.on.  I have not found a way around this.

```
var self = require('sdk/self');

// a dummy function, to show how tests work.
// to see how to test this function, look at test/test-index.js
function dummy(text, callback) {
  callback(text);
}

exports.dummy = dummy;
//ignore above
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var text;
var size;

function setTextAndSize(texts, siz) {
    text = texts;
    size = siz;
}

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.example.com",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("myscript.js"),
  contentScriptOptions: {"text" : text, "size" : size}//text and size are undefined even though I set them line 57.
});

var control_window = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("control.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("controlget.js")
});

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "myicon",
  label: "My add on",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

control_window.on("show", function() {
  control_window.port.emit("show");
});

function opentabb() {
    tabs.open("http://example.com");
}

control_window.port.on("start", function (text, size, info, link) {
    console.log("Text: "+text+" Size: "+size);//this works
    control_window.hide();
    setTextAndSize(code, size);//does not set for some reason
    opentabb();
});

control_window.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
  console.log(text);
  control_window.hide();
});

function handleClick(state) {
    control_window.show();
}
```

I want to set the global variables text and size from `control_window.port.on()`

If I initialize `var text = "test"` and `var size = "testsize"` the pagemod reads `"test"` and `"testsize"` but `control_window.port.on()` still will not set `var text;` or `var size`.

Answer (score 0):

> From Firefox 30 onwards, the execution environment for content scripts
>   has changed, so content scripts can't directly share objects with page
>   scripts. This affects the use of custom events to send messages from
>   content scripts to page scripts.

You will need to use `window.postMessage()` to communicate between your content scripts.

You could do something along these lines.

Within your `PageMod` content script.

```
// myscript.js
window.postMessage({text: self.options.text, size: self.options.size},'*');
```

Within your `Panel` content script.

```
// controlget.js
window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
  self.port.emit('start', event.data.text, event.data.size, 'some info', window.location.href);
});
```

Best of luck.